# how to increase the number of views in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How can we increase the number of views in a single property of google analytics.

I want to use only single property in my sites, hence need more number of views.

Around 500.

How do I get it?

Thank you.

Comment: This is off topic as it isn't related to coding and should be posted to the Webmasters forum. However, to comment, you can't increase the number of views unless you are Premium users and you reach out to Google.

Answer (score 0):

As [per documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1102152?hl=en)

```
Contact your support representative if you need more properties or views.
```

Since for the free version you will not have a support representative you need to be a GA Premium customer (or possibly a really really major adwords spender) if you want additional views.